# How can I update a make variable from a target?

Tags: shell, makefile, environment-variables

I have a bunch of shell scripts and Makefiles that call each other in various and interesting ways.  For the entire project, there is one thing to build, and some (not all) of the scripts and Makefile targets require this thing to be built.  None of the scripts or Makefile targets change anything about the thing being built, so I want to only build once per shell script/Makefile invocation.  I partially accomplish this by setting the environment variable DO_NOT_BUILD when the thing is built before calling one of the child shell scripts/Makefiles.  So, I want to build the thing whenever it needs to be built and DO_NOT_BUILD is not set, and then let all the children know not to rebuild, so DO_NOT_BUILD should be set after building.  This is easy to do in shell scripts, but I'm finding it very hard to do with Makefiles.  Here's my toy Makefile:

```
PARENT_DO_NOT_BUILD := $(DO_NOT_BUILD)
export DO_NOT_BUILD

.PHONY: build
build: DO_NOT_BUILD := true
build:
    if [ -z "$(PARENT_DO_NOT_BUILD)" ]; then echo "Building now"; fi

.PHONY: do_thing_with_build
do_thing_with_build: build
    echo "DO_NOT_BUILD=$${DO_NOT_BUILD}"

.PHONY: do_thing_without_build
do_thing_without_build:
    echo "DO_NOT_BUILD=$${DO_NOT_BUILD}"
```

My desired behavior is (omitting echoed commands):

```
$ make do_thing_without_build
  DO_NOT_BUILD=
$ make do_thing_with_build
  Building now
  DO_NOT_BUILD=true
$ export DO_NOT_BUILD=true && make do_thing_without_build
  DO_NOT_BUILD=true
$ export DO_NOT_BUILD=true && make do_thing_with_build
  DO_NOT_BUILD=true
```

Instead, `make do_thing_with_build` has an empty `$DO_NOT_BUILD` environment variable because setting `DO_NOT_BUILD := true` only applies to the `build` target and not the `do_thing_with_build` target.

How can I condition the action taken in my `build` target on the an environment variable presented to make while presenting an updated environment variable to child actions if the target was invoked?  Or alternately, how can I update DO_NOT_BUILD when the `build` target is invoked?  Or really, how can I produce my desired behavior above?

Comment: delete a flag file in the parent; test for existence in children - first one can create it so others skip

Comment: I'm not totally against file-based execution control, but I'm not sure how it would work robustly.  How would a Makefile know if it was the "first one" rather than a child?  I could do the reverse (create a file indicating build is complete in the parent), but then if execution ended early, I don't know how to guarantee that file would be cleaned up so that the next run would build.

Comment: `rm DO_NOT_BUILD && make` / `touch DO_NOT_BUILD && make` ? (the build target checks non-existence before running, and creates after running)

Comment: I guess I can wrap access to each Makefile in its own shell script ("rm -f DO_NOT_BUILD && make" is a much poorer user experience than "make" or "./do_thing.sh"), but then I'm just largely bypassing make.  Is this use case beyond make's capabilities?

Comment: with GNU make, you could use `MAKELEVEL` to decide whether to initialise the flagfile or check it

Comment: No process can manipulate the environment of its parent (or more distant ancestors).  In particular, nothing you put in your makefile can produce a change in the value of `DO_NOT_BUILD` in the shell from which you run `make`.

Comment: Target-specific variables are scoped to the target that defines them and its prerequisites. They are not visible in the context of other targets.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a bunch of shell scripts and Makefiles that call each other in various and interesting ways. [...]

That sounds horrifying.  `make` is not to be mistaken for a scripting tool.  People create all kinds of trouble for themselves by trying to use it that way, and the big trap there is that if you hack on it hard enough then you can often get it to work.  The results generally exhibit non-trivial degrees of nastiness.

If there is only one artifact to be built then there should be no need for more than one makefile.  Additionally, if the one artifact has appropriate prerequisites declared for it then `make` handles your build-once problem naturally.  `make`ing the artifact again when it is already up to date with respect to its prerequisites will not result in its recipe being executed.  The various scripts in the system could then each `make the_thing` if they require it to be up to date, and be confident that it will be built only if it is out of date.

---

As for your specific question, I don't follow why your particular example is representative of what you want to do, but one way you could achieve the results you specify would be simply to move the definition of the target-specific variable:

```
PARENT_DO_NOT_BUILD := $(DO_NOT_BUILD)
export DO_NOT_BUILD

.PHONY: build
build:
    if [ -z "$(PARENT_DO_NOT_BUILD)" ]; then echo "Building now"; fi

.PHONY: do_thing_with_build
do_thing_with_build: DO_NOT_BUILD := true
do_thing_with_build: build
    echo "DO_NOT_BUILD=$${DO_NOT_BUILD}"

.PHONY: do_thing_without_build
do_thing_without_build:
    echo "DO_NOT_BUILD=$${DO_NOT_BUILD}"
```

And I reiterate my comments on the question here:

- No process can manipulate the environment of its parent (or more distant ancestors). In particular, nothing you put in your makefile can produce a change in the value of `DO_NOT_BUILD` in the shell from which you run `make`.
- Target-specific variables are scoped to the target that defines them and its prerequisites. They are not visible in the context of other targets.

Comment: This seems workable -- thanks.  The down side is that any target depending on the `build` target must also manually set a target-specific variable.  This is far better than hacking file flags, but it's still a little disappointing I can't achieve communication of build state to children merely with make's declarative structure (target X depends on build, therefore X should set an environment variable a certain way).

Comment: You are welcome, @Ben, but again, *`make` is not to be mistaken for a scripting tool*.  Reread the second paragraph of this answer for an alternative approach that would better leverage `make`'s strengths.

Comment: Thanks for the further comment.  I think the challenge is the .PHONY targets -- basically, something external to the Makefile (including other Makefiles) doesn't know whether a .PHONY target has been built, and the difficulty I'm experiencing comes from trying to communicate that.  I'm thinking that adding placeholder files for non-file targets will resolve this cleanly -- for instance, when I build a Docker image, I'll also `touch` a docker-image file; when I deploy a server, I'll also `touch` a server-up file.